# AppendingTransformer in maven-shade-plugin generates one file with duplicate keys

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot project that I'm shading with maven-shade-plugin. I use an AppendingTransformer to append all the META-INF/spring.factories into one.

I noticed that the generated file contained multiple time the same keys with different values. That prevents my server from starting up.

Is it the normal behavior or is it a bug? Is there a way to merge the values?

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>

                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mindgeek.cloud.downloader.application.Application</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the result file:

```
# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader

# Run Listeners
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=\
org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener

# Error Reporters
org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionReporter=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers

# Application Context Initializers
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.context.ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.DelegatingApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.web.context.ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer

# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.ClearCachesApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.builder.ParentContextCloserApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.AnsiOutputApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.DelegatingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener

# Environment Post Processors
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.env.SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor

# Failure Analyzers
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanCurrentlyInCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BindFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BindValidationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.UnboundConfigurationPropertyFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ConnectorStartFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.PortInUseFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueFailureAnalyzer

# FailureAnalysisReporters
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter

# Initializers
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener

# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer

# Auto Configuration Import Listeners
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReportAutoConfigurationImportListener

# Auto Configuration Import Filters
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition

# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cloud.CloudAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.solr.SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.jest.JestAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.influx.InfluxDbAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.core.ReactorCoreAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.reactive.WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration

# Failure analyzers
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBeanCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.NonUniqueSessionRepositoryFailureAnalyzer

# Template availability providers
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.template.TemplateAvailabilityProvider=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.JspTemplateAvailabilityProvider

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.cloudfoundry.servlet.CloudFoundryActuatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.cloudfoundry.reactive.ReactiveCloudFoundryActuatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionsReportEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.ShutdownEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.env.EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.influx.InfluxDbHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jms.JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jolokia.JolokiaEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.logging.LogFileWebEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.logging.LoggersEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mail.MailHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.management.HeapDumpWebEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.management.ThreadDumpEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.amqp.RabbitMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.atlas.AtlasMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.datadog.DatadogMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.ganglia.GangliaMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.graphite.GraphiteMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.influx.InfluxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.jmx.JmxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.newrelic.NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.signalfx.SignalFxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.statsd.StatsdMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.wavefront.WavefrontMetricsExportAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.client.RestTemplateMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.reactive.WebFluxMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.neo4j.Neo4jHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.scheduling.ScheduledTasksEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.session.SessionsEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.solr.SolrHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.trace.http.HttpTraceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.trace.http.HttpTraceEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.mappings.MappingsEndpointAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveManagementContextAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.reactive.WebFluxEndpointManagementContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.jersey.JerseyWebEndpointManagementContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.jersey.JerseyManagementChildContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveManagementChildContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletManagementChildContextConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointChildContextConfiguration

org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MissingRequiredConfigurationFailureAnalyzer

org.springframework.beans.BeanInfoFactory=org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory
```

Comment: Why are you using maven-shade-plugin instead of the spring-boot-plugin ?

Comment: You are right, I now generate a war file with the jars in and it works fine.